# How to get the field values in firebase cloud database?

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

[image]

```
let reference = Firestore
            .firestore()
            .collection(FBKeys.CollectionPath.users)
            .document(uid)
        reference.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let dataDescription = document?.data()
                print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Document does not exist")
            }
        }
```

I have created a cloud database using firebase. I have collection name is "users" and I have email, favoriteArtsts, name, uid as the fields. What I want to do is I want to add more artists to the favoriteArtsts array. However, to do so, I have to first get the reference to the array. By following the firebase instructions, I was able to get the user_id. The code above is the code I have tried. The code shows all the fields. However, I don't know how to get the favoriteArtsts values only. Is there a way to get the favoriteArtsts values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a single field by doing `document.get("favoriteAritsts")` *(notice your typo in `favoriteAritsts` in your screenshots*.

You can also do `document.data()["favoriteAritsts"]`

Both of the above will give you a return type of `Any?` so you would need to do any optional cast of either one with `as? [String]`:

`let array = document.get("favoriteAritsts") as? [String]`

Comment: Thank you! It worked! So, I used var array = document.get("favoriteAritsts") as? [String] array?.append(artist). I tried to add the artist by append. It gets added when I print it, but in the firebase it does not show up. Do I have to do something else than append?

Comment: Great -- you can accept the answer as correct by clicking the green check mark next to the answer and, if it was helpful, you can click the up arrow to upvote it. Yes, you do have to do more than just append. You can see the Firebase documentation at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data on how to add data. You'll be using methods like `setData` or `updateData`